.NET 6 System.Dynamic object implemented in class
I'm using .NET 6 and I'm trying to declare and bind something like this:
appsettings.json:
{
  "QueryConfigList": [
    {
      "TableName": "Live",
      "QueryText": "SELECT * FROM Live",
      "AdditionalInfo": "Users only",
      "ObjectClass": {
        "TagName": "string",
        "Value1": "float"
      }
    },
    {
      "TableName": "Orders",
      "QueryText": "SELECT * FROM Orders",
      "AdditionalInfo": "Completed orders",
      "ObjectClass": {
        "TagName": "string",
        "Value2": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}

In C#:
public class QueryConfig
{
    public string? TableName { get; set; }
    public string? QueryText { get; set; }
    public string? AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    public dynamic? ObjectClass { get; set; }
}

public class QueryConfigList
{
    public ICollection<QueryConfig>? QueryConfig { get; set; }
}

I've coded something like this in startup.cs:
var queryConfigList = builder.Configuration.GetSection("QueryConfigList").Get<List<QueryConfig>>();

but I got null - what is wrong? ChatGpt swears - this should work

Your code works for me, perhaps you're constructing your configuration incorrectly?
You don't need the QueryConfigList class since your config section is a list already.
Code that I tried in a brand new project with your json file:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var queryList = config.GetSection("QueryConfigList").Get<List<QueryConfig>>();
Console.WriteLine($"QueryCt={queryList.Count}");

public class QueryConfig
{
    public string? TableName { get; set; }
    public string? QueryText { get; set; }
    public string? AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    public dynamic? ObjectClass { get; set; }
}

UPDATE
Upon further inspection, I had used newer versions of the configuration libraries.  Looks like a fix was added in 7.0.0 version of the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder library (looks like this commit? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/78118).
The following .csproj file works.  Notably, it's a .NET 6 exe with 6.* versioned dependencies with the exception of the Config Binder reference which is v7.0.
This library should be backwards compatible with a .NET 6 project.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>



Did you run against .NET 6 with corresponding versions of libraries (I haven't, I used .NET 8 and got non-null object too for my answer)? 2. Have you checked that ObjectClass is actually usable? Because in my tests it wasn't (I will check again later).


You're right, i was using newer library versions.  See update.

You are right, friend!!!! Thanks.

Based on the provided data you can use Dictionary<string, string> for the dynamic part:
public class QueryConfig
{
    //...
    public Dictionary<string, string>? ObjectClass { get; set; }
}

If that is not suitable for you then I'm afraid you will need to parse the config manually. Something to get you started:
foreach (var entry in builder.Configuration.GetSection("QueryConfigList").GetChildren())
{
    foreach (var field in entry.GetChildren())
    {
        if (field.Key == "ObjectClass")
        {
            // process dynamic part
        }
    }
}

